# Install reddit on amazon webserver?

Tags: postgresql, installation, reddit

I have followed every step as [given here](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/Install-guide). I installed all the servers and libraries but when I set the PostgreSQL server it hangs stating the follows on the terminal

> LOG:  database system was shut down at 2014-01-22 01:53:52 UTC
>
> LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
>
> LOG:  autovacuum launcher started

What to do?

Comment: And you "set the PostgreSQL server" with what command, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're referring to these lines:

> Finally, start up the server.
>
> ```
> $ sudo -u postgres postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
> ```

If so, that starts the PostgreSQL server in blocking mode. It is running. It won't exit until told to, and that terminal won't return. It sounds like you'd prefer it to exit and keep running in the background, in which case you should use `pg_ctl` to start the server instead.

The bigger problem is that those instructions are pretty stupid. You shouldn't be `initdb`'ing a new cluster and starting a new server; you almost certainly have one installed and running. It's hard to say, since you didn't say how you installed PostgreSQL, what OS you're on, what PostgreSQL version you have, etc.

In general, though, you should be connecting to your existing PostgreSQL install. Use that, don't `initdb` a new one. That's why the guide you were reading says:

> *This section may be unnecessary on your system. Check if your installation of postgres created a default database and start scripts for you.*

Since you're using a stock Ubuntu install, please start by reading the [Ubuntu introduction to PostgreSQL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL).

Then follow the setup guide starting at "create the database".

Comment: I am trying to install reddit on ubuntu 12.04.5 and the PostgresSql version is 9.1. I installed PostgeSQL using 'sudo apt-get install postgresql' command. I created a user and then run all the commands as given in the install guide.

Comment: @user3221714 The install guide assumes you have at least a basic understanding of PostgreSQL. In your case you already have a PostgreSQL install, so you do not need to `initdb`. Just create a database inside your existing install and connect to it instead. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-createdb.html and the rest of the PostgreSQL tutorial, as well as the Ubuntu guide linked in the answer edit above.

Comment: @user3221714 I've now rewritten the wiki article to simplify it. Tell me if that helps.

Comment: I have managed to run the reddit clone on my server... Thanks Craig

Comment: @user3221714 Please accept the answer, then; tick-box under the vote arrows.